# Он скорее тень, а не человек

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем синтаксически является *а не человек*?

*Он скорее тень, **а не человек**.*

Спасибо!

Comment: _**Он**_ -- подлежащее, _**тень, не человек**_ -- однородные сказуемые (именные части составных именных сказуемых).

Comment: Слава, а почему комментарий, а не ответ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> чем синтаксически является а *не человек*?
>
> Он скорее тень, а не человек.

***Он*** -- подлежащее,

***тень, не человек*** -- однородные сказуемые (именные части составных именных сказуемых).

Comment: Slava, я правильно понимаю: это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, соединённое союзом "а"?

Comment: Да, простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, соединённ**ыми** союзом "а".